# Screen Flow Variables are not updating when re-visiting the Screen

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

I have a screen flow with 2 screens, on screen 2 based on the value provided in Screen 1 I am defining a formula variable and using it as a default value in Screen 2 text field, this is working well when i first visit screen 1 and move to screen 2.

But, when I go back to screen 1 from screen 2 and modify the data which impacts the formula value, in debug mode I see the formula is updating successfully but once I land back to the screen 2 the default value is not reflecting the new formula value but showing same value as before moving back from screen 2 to screen 1.

Is there a way to make screen 2 values updates based on the formula field when we revisit?

Comment: Do you have `Refresh inputs to incorporate changes elsewhere in the flow` selected on that particular screen? - [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_refresh_inputs_on_flow_pages.htm&type=5)

Comment: thanks @KrisGoncalves, I am not able to find this option anywhere on the flows, not sure if this is specific to Salesforce Scheduler or available in flows in general.

Comment: Oh, apologies - I misread your question. That is for LWC components on the flow screen. This is a screen flow with only a display text (and other standard flow inputs)?

Comment: You are right @KrisGoncalves, I am using standard screen flow with text inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Update: [With Winter '24](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_revisited_screen_values.htm&release=246&type=5), they added this behavior to some types

> You can now refresh the values of choice, Date, Date & Time, Number, Currency, Text, and Long Text Area components when a user navigates to a previous screen and then forward again.

So if your field type matches those, you should be able to select in `advanced` the option for `refresh inputs to incorporate changes elsewhere in the flow`.

---

Original Answer: I believe this is **expected** behavior and how Flow works. They released the ability for LWC components to define whether inputs are refreshed or use values from when the user last visited.

However, there's no such feature for standard flow **inputs** (as noted in my comment, display text will incorporate changes). This is somewhat called out in the [Spring '21](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_revisit_screen_values.htm&type=5&release=230) release notes that released the LWC component feature:

> When a user navigates to a previous screen, then proceeds forward to a screen that they visited already, the flow can refresh screen component values. Changes elsewhere in the flow are incorporated in the refreshed values. Previously, a screen component always used the same values that the user entered. **The options for revisited screen component values are available only for Lightning components**.

Unofficialsf covers this behavior in the [article](https://unofficialsf.com/optimizing-lightning-component-inputs-and-outputs-in-flow-screens/) covering optimizing lightning component inputs and outputs in flow screens. They provide a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiYQUiJfVUk&ab_channel=AlexEdelstein) highlighting this behavior that matches your question.

> Text fields in flow are optimized for a case where the value may need to be initialized to a default value, but once the user enters something else, **the text field should not be reset.**

---

So what can you do to workaround the behavior of Flow?

Considering the behavior above, you're really left only with the option to leverage a LWC component for this specific use-case. You'd create a LWC for these types of inputs where you want to provide a default value that should respond to user-provided changes if they re-visit. You'd just select that option to refresh inputs.